# Determining the radius of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Oh sorry everyone, I have just written the problem.
Thanks for the warning.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x+3)^n}{n\cdot 3^{n}}$$

I could not determine the radius of convergence and the interval of convergence of the series where n starts at 1 and goes up to infinity.

Can anyone help me? Thanks for any help! :))

Comment: As a start, replace $x+3$ by $t$. Then Ratio Test works nicely. Root Test also.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : It's not really necessary to do that substitution.  The ratio test works regardless of whether you do that.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Certainly. But the substitution may bring the student into more familiar territory.

Comment: As @DonAntonio says, 10 questions, 0 accepted answers. You would do well to upvote helpful answers and accept one for all previous questions with acceptable answers.

Comment: oh i see. thank you for the explanantion @johnD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're looking at
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x+3)^n}{n\cdot 3^n}.
$$

Applying the ratio test, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{\left(\frac{(x+3)^{n+1}}{(n+1)\cdot 3^{n+1}}\right)}{\left(\frac{(x+3)^n}{n\cdot 3^n}\right)} \right| = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{n(x+3)}{3(n+1)}\right| = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{|x+3|}{3}\cdot\frac{n}{n+1}\right).
$$
The factor $\dfrac{|x+3|}{3}$ does not change as $n$ changes, so it can be pulled out:
$$
=\frac{|x+3|}{3} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n+1} = \frac{|x+3|}{3}\cdot 1
$$

Thus the series converges if $\dfrac{|x+3|}{3}<1$ and diverges if $\dfrac{|x+3|}{3}>1$.

Now solve the inequality
$$
\frac{|x+3|}{3}<1
$$
for $x$.